# What is the point of the ethernet plug: SoundCraft Si Compact 32?

Tags: mixer

After searching the internet, I can't find out what the ethernet plug for the mixer is for. Can you use it to remote control the mixer from a computer? Or what is it for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the port in V2 software to trigger HiQnet Venue Presets programmed via London Architect and System Architect; the iPad app to directly control the Si Compact is still in BETA test so it's not a 'product' on the web site but you can register for information at http://www.soundcraft.com/apps/visi-remote.aspx.

If you have further questions please use the Soundcraft web site Facebook pages or contact your distributor to make  enquiries since Soundcraft do not actively participate and monitor any forums.

Regards, 
Soundcraft-Studer Product Management Team

Answer (score 2):

According their [product page](http://www.soundcraft.com/products/product.aspx?pid=182) (download the [PDF brochure](http://www.soundcraft.com/downloads/fetchfile.aspx?cat_id=brochures&id=3364)) the ethernet port is for [HiQnet](http://www.akg.com/site/products/powerslave,id,948,pid,948,nodeid,2,_language,EN.html) connectivity, which is a protocol that allows for both control and monitoring of all connected devices.

Comment: Yes, but what is that?

Comment: Can I remote control the mixer with my computer?

Comment: It appears so. Did you click on the link for HiQnet and read more about it?

Comment: Yes. I had a chat with some people that said that they were developing an iPad app for remote controlling the mixer. So, I suppose this is done through the HiQnet. But I can't find anything more about it on the SoundCraft website. Can I just download the software from AKG, and it'll work?

Comment: I mean, I can't seem to find anything on this topic when it comes to the computer.

Comment: You should take a look at hiqnet.harmanpro.com as it has more information. The AKG app is just for microphones, there is also an app for Crown amplifiers. HiQnet allows for the control of all the pieces of a Harman audio system.